# Method for getting jQuery element or value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set up a class that allows me to get an input/select element's value *or* the element itself:

```
My.Class = {
    property: function(e){
        var t = '#element_id';
        return My.Helper.fetch(t, e);
    }
}
My.Helper = {
    fetch: function(t,e){
        if (e == true) {
            return jQuery(t);
        };
        return jQuery(t).val();
    }
}


var element = My.Class.property(true);
var elementValue = My.Class.property();
```

This works great, but when I have dozens of properties, the code repeats quite a bit:

```
My.Class = {
    property: function(e){
        var t = '#element_id';
        return My.Helper.fetch(t, e);
    },
    property_b: function(e){
        var t = '#element_id_b';
        return My.Helper.fetch(t, e);
    },
    property_c: function(e){
        var t = '#element_id_c';
        return My.Helper.fetch(t, e);
    },
    property_d: function(e){
        var t = '#element_id_d';
        return My.Helper.fetch(t, e);
    }
}
```

How can I can I construct these properties without having to repeat myself so often? Keep in mind that my example property names and element names cannot always be consistent.

Comment: Why don't you pass the selector as parameter to property method? Anyway, i don't see any purpose of all your code: `jQuery('#element_id')` or `jQuery('#element_id').val()` would be enough

Comment: Why not just `var element = My.Helper.fetch('#element_id', true);`

Comment: i understand that you created these methods to get some reference to some element or to get the value of that element but why not just use the way Wolff already pointed ? any specific reason ?

Comment: also your code looks repetitive, the only thing that's changing in your `property_` methods is the selector. Why don't you just pass your selector to some generic method like `getProperty(selector)` ? Also I think you don't need a boolean to decide whether to return an element or a value, in either case you're creating a $ object, so why not just re-use the first one and use that element reference to get the value using `element.val();`

Comment: All good points. Thanks. @A.Wolff - simply calling the generic jQuery methods is not enough. Some properties are groups of elements and those elements might be present in any number of other properties. Calling each element individually all the time is going to be a lot more repetitive than what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you should just have a `get_property(selector_string)` method that does this for you. The other alternative is that on instantiation the object could get a list of elements that you'd be able to 'reget' if the DOM's changed.

Comment: Having a generic method like that makes things very confusing when I need to get a group of elements. `get_property('#selector_a,#selector_b,#selector_c,#selector_d,#selector_e')` gets awfully long winded. The point of the code is to be able to use `My.Class.group_a(true)` to get a group of elements, or `My.Class.group_a()` to get the values of the elements (sometimes individually, sometimes as a running total).